# Threads share cpu only if sleep

Tags: python, multithreading

So I have this code:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

counter = 0
TOTAL = 10_000

def some_work(name):
     global counter
     print("Doing work from :", name)
     while counter<TOTAL:
         if counter % 1000 == 0:
             print("work from :", name)
         counter+=1
         sleep(0.001)         #<--- This right here


num_workers = 2
threads = []

for worker in range(num_workers):
        work = lambda :some_work(worker)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=work, daemon=True)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
        sleep(0.5)

[t.join() for t in threads]
```

Which gives me a nice output of asynchronous work. The thing is if I comment out the annotated sleep(0.001) , then only one thread works. The other one jumps in only after the first one has finished. The output to that is :

```
Doing work from : 0
work from : 0
work from : 0
work from : 0
work from : 0
work from : 0
work from : 0
work from : 0
work from : 0
work from : 0
work from : 0
Doing work from : 1
```

I have larger piece of code where the same phenomenon occurs with or without sleep. (No reason to show that code , it would be too large). I would just like to know when does this happen, a thread hogs all the cpu to itself and everything actually works sequentially?

Comment: There is GIL in Python: only one thread at a time can do anything.

Comment: But what if I do use sleep and the same thing happens? Shouldn't another thread come into play?

Comment: Yes, he comes when the first is sleeping. But he also falls asleep, that's why you see `0 1 0 1 0 1` like if they are executed simultaneously.

Comment: It does not take long for a modern computer to count to ten thousand. I'm guessing that when you take out the `sleep` calls, the first thread is able to complete its task before the second thread even starts to run. Maybe try tacking on about three more zeroes, as in, `TOTAL = 10_000_000` and `if counter % 1_000_000:`

Comment: P.S., Tried it on my own workstation, and the first thread got past four million counts before the second thread produced any output.